# Image blending with laplacian pyramids yields bad image

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I'm trying to implement an image blending algorithm that receives two images
im1, im2 and a binary mask and blends the two image accroding to that mask.
I'm using the following formula:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxz34.png

to build the laplacian pyramid of the blended image and then I reconstruct it
to receive the final image.

my code:

```
mask = mask.astype(np.float64)
pyr_im1, filter_vec = build_laplacian_pyramid(im1, max_levels,
                                              filter_size_im)
pyr_im2 = build_laplacian_pyramid(im2, max_levels,
                                  filter_size_im)[0]
pyr_mask = build_gaussian_pyramid(mask, max_levels,
                                  filter_size_mask)[0]

# build the blended laplacian pyramid

l_out = [np.multiply(pyr_mask[k], pyr_im1[k])
         + np.multiply(1 - pyr_mask[k], pyr_im2[k])
         for k in range(len(pyr_im1))]

im_blend = laplacian_to_image(l_out, filter_vec, [1] * len(l_out))
im_blend = np.clip(im_blend, 0, 1)  # clip values to the range of [0,1]

return im_blend
```

Where mask is a binary mask with values of 0 or 1, im1 and im2 are np.float64
images normalized to the range of (0,1). The functions build_laplacian_pyramid,
build_gaussian_pyramid and laplacian_to_image work perfectly-I have tested
them and made sure that they work properly. When I use this code to try and
blend two images I get something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NlKv.png

Are there any apperent issues with my code that can come to mind?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm not sure what exactly is wrong but I think you need to reverse the mask when applying the blend.

Here is my code that seems to work:

```
def laplacianSameSize(outerImage, innerImage, mask, levels):

gpCEye = gaussianPyramid(innerImage, levels)
lpCEye = laplacianPyramid(gpCEye)
gpFrame = gaussianPyramid(outerImage, levels)
lpFrame = laplacianPyramid(gpFrame)

gpMask = gaussianPyramid(mask, levels)

gpMask.reverse()
LS = []
#Appling the mask
for lFrame, lCEye, gMask in zip(lpFrame, lpCEye, gpMask):
    lFrame[gMask == 255] = lCEye[gMask == 255]
    LS.append(lFrame)

# now reconstruct
ls_ = LS[0]
for i in range(1,levels+1):
    size = (LS[i].shape[1], LS[i].shape[0])
    ls_ = cv2.pyrUp(ls_,dstsize=size)
    ls_ = ls_ + LS[i]

#Making it above 0 before becoming uint8
bound(ls_)
return ls_.astype(np.uint8)
```

With functions

```
def laplacianPyramid(gp):
levels = len(gp) - 1
lp = [gp[levels]]
for i in range(levels, 0, -1):
    size = (gp[i - 1].shape[1], gp[i - 1].shape[0])
    GE = cv2.pyrUp(gp[i], dstsize=size)
    L = gp[i - 1] - GE
    lp.append(L)
return lp

def gaussianPyramid(img, num_levels):
lower = img.copy()
gp = [np.float32(lower)]
for i in range(num_levels):
    lower = cv2.pyrDown(lower)
    gp.append(np.float32(lower))
return gp

def bound(im):
   im[im < 0] = 0
   im[im > 255] = 255
```

I also make sure to use floats until the end then bounding it within 0 to 255.

Hope this helps!